# How do I use Business Process Modelling Notation (BPMN) in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, bpmn

I'd like to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 application in C# that is based on a BPMN diagram for its high level workflow, with the ability to "code behind" each of the steps. Is this possible? I know of Windows Workflow Foundation, but the notation and what-not are quite different from BPMN, and it is not a preferred method if there is an alternative out there. Thanks!

Comment: You can consider using [Nevron Diagram](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-overview.aspx). It has a lot of the Visio features. It also support importing from Visio and you can visualize quite complex interactive diagrams under ASP.NET/MVC.

Answer (score 0):

do you already have some BPMN diagram ?

I would advice to you to consider existing BPMN engine that consume BPMN diagram and could be called by C#.NET

For instance bonita BPM provide some [REST API](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/rest-api-overview) that would help you: you may build your own C#.NET front end that will use the Bonita BPM Engine as back end.

Then with connectors you will be able to call some code behind each steps,  using connectors (as Bonita BPM Engine is a Java application, you may need to expose your code as a REST service or equivalent).

Another thread I found about BPMN and Windows WF: [What are the differences between open source BPM tools (such as Activiti, bonita) & Windows Workflow Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161089/what-are-the-diffences-between-open-source-bpm-tools-such-as-activiti-bonita)

Comment: Thanks Renaud. I do have some BPMN diagrams done up in Visio, and was hoping to use them. It would have been best if Windows WF consume BPMN - then I wouldn't have this problem to deal with. :) I think my concern is, if I use Bonita or other non-Microsoft engine, how compatible will it be with our C# application?