# Why to use workflow system and what are my options?

Tags: workflow, business-process-management

I was reading the following post:
[Why use Windows Workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513657/why-use-windows-workflow)

Now wf concept looks promising technology for lowering company costs on business process implementation. MS WF looks that it does not have everything for fast implementation. What are other wf/bpm options for fast implementation?

Comment: Take a look at MissionControl - it's a lightweight Workflow/Business Rule Engine hybrid. It is ideal for situations where you do not need a ton of bells and whistles, and would rather write code than deal with a cumbersome flowchart gui. Because it simpler than most other products, you spend more time getting work done and less time learning and integrating the overweight alternatives. http://www.techtoniclabs.com/MissionControl Disclosure: I am the founder of Techtonic Labs. If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with workflow engines/systems (OpenText, K2.net, Metastorm, MS WorkFlow Foundation, ...) for past 10 years and I can say that wf technology can be very useful, however it's not suitable for solving all type of problems.

Basicly it's ment to solve process oriented tasks. You would ask your self what does this mean!? Well process is any entity that has start, duration and end. If you look the tipical company is buildup with processes. Apparently storing some final reports in such system would not be the goal... The power shows up when those tasks needs to be processed in controled manner or new process route is required. Classic implementation would require for developer to write additional code, good wf system will let you implement route change in a second without line of code and process versioning is not a problem. This in just one of the benifits.

You should look at wf system as platform for fast process development, monitoring, optimization and versioning. It should give you all the tools needed for BPM life cycle. Here you can find what I am talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management

In my professional career I have developed one wf engine and one fully wf system based on MS .net technology. If you are interested in details please visit my web site:
http://www.gp-solutions.si/business/Product.aspx?s=pro&id=1&cat=2 With this system you can develope new process with all the forms, monitoring, security, documents,... in less then 10 min. You can not do this in traditional way of development. Save time and money is the name of the game here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a commercial alternative for fast BPM implementation I worked with two .NET based platforms in the past - K2.net and PNMSoft.
I personally like PNMSoft (http://www.pnmsoft.com/) since it is native .NET, it supports WF and other technologies and is extremely fast and easy to use.

If you're looking for open-source alternatives, there are some .NET based ones like Bonita (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bonita/) but don't expect it to be as quick and easy...

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are several open source BPMS under convenient license models.

For instance the Eclipse Process Manager "Stardust" (http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/) is a comprehensive and mature Java open source BPMS. Its commercial version is used in several products for different industries, also in combination with .NET.

- browser-based or Eclipse based process modeler
- Process engine in Spring or EJB mode, e.g. Tomcat
- Web Service and Java APIs (SOAP, REST)
- OOTB portal for workflow execution, business control center and administration
- User interface mashup feature to include arbitrary UI technologies in workflow steps
- embedded DMS
- strong ootb system integration capabilities (JMS, WS, Camel,...)
- Amazon Web Service Stardust image available (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Knowledge_Base/Getting_Started/RTE_on_AWS)
- commerical support and SaaS on demand offering available
- suitable e.g. for human centric workflow, ETL, low latency and high volume message processing, document centric worklfow and document management,...

Best regards

Rob