# best way to construct a workflow app in .net

Tags: f#, workflow-foundation, agent, akka.net, orleans

I need to construct a dynamic workflow application in .net that will basically allow to create, monitor, pause, restart, persist and dynamically update a workflow. Every node of the workflow is a high demanding computing task that could take several hours and the workflows are going to be composed of at least 20 nodes.

For the moment, it seems that the best solution is to use WF4 but looking around I've found agent-based programming in F#, Orleans or Akka.NET very appealing to implement a workflow solution and in contrast to WF4 there is not so much plumbing to learn. Is it a good idea to start a solution with agent-based programming or should I stay with WF4?

Comment: they are different things really, I'm not massively familiar with WF4 ummm...I personally would start with WF4 and "that could take several hours" sounds like the sort of things that live in a workflow world, with all the "long running transatction" type bells and whistles

Comment: It seems that WF4 has a divided opinion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104099/when-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation (look at the second answer) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513657/why-use-windows-workflow

Answer (score 2):

**`<edit>`**

To answer your question on building an agent-based model, that is the best approach in my view. It makes it easier to debug and maintain too, while separating out the "driver" of the whole operation (i.e. you can swap out WF and replace it with another apparatus).

**`</edit>`**

WF4 can be used for driving your long-running business logic. The best approach I've used is a workflow that simply kicks off "agent processes", and while the agent(s) are working, the WF instance hibernates waiting to be awakened by an agent.

In a nutshell, something like this approach:

- Have a "orchestration" process that is in charge of starting new workflows and hydrating persisted workflows.
- And have an "agent" process (or processes) that actually run your long running tasks.

> The Orchestration Process

This process is in charge of starting a brand new workflow instance. Your workflow would simply kick off an agent process to do the actual work. The workflow instance would then hibernate.

This process would also wait for requests to resume hibernated workflow instances. In essence, a workflow instance would be "running" for only a few moments, and delegating the real work to other threads / processes.

One way of implementing the orchestration process is as a web service. It makes it easy for an agent process to call back to it to wake up a slumbering workflow instance when the agent is done.

> The Agent Process

This process will have the actual know-how of performing the work. When invoked by the orchestration process, some information is given to it to know which context (i.e. business object(s)) it should execute against. When it finishes, the agent informs the orchestration process that it finished.

> Back To The Orchestration Process

When an agent finishes its task, it makes a call back to the orchestration process that the context is ready to move on to the next item in the flow. The orchestration process would then hydrate that context's workflow, and resume it.

The workflow could decide that another long running task is up next, and thus spins up another agent process to delegate the task to, and then hibernate the workflow instance again. And this cycle continues until the workflow instance reaches the end.

> The "Dynamic" Workflow Part

I think your referring to updating an "already in progress" workflow, correct? If so, WF4.5 has the capability of allowing for this. I've never implemented it (yet) but it is feasible from what I've read.

The concept involves adding some metadata about the version of your workflow being executed. WF would take care of launching a dynamic activity update, which you have control in coordinating.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your point. In my case, the nodes of the workflow will be mostly R scripts that I will need to wrap in order to provide some options. Then I will need to provide the orchestration of the workflow. My point is that even though WF provides very nice features (persistance and dynamic updates), it doesn't seem developper friendly. So, is it better to use WF for only the orchastration part or should I use somthing else like Akka.Net ?

Comment: There is a learning curve to picking up WF, but it's not insanely tricky. The bright side is it does provide a lot out of the box, which is a huge plus. The caveat is some documentation hunting that is needed for some if the functionality. There are lots of blogs about various things about it, so that's a plus these days. I say if you can find documentation on the features that you would likely use it, then go for it.

Comment: This "orchestration" idea of @ajawad987 is the killer approach, it uses WF for it's strength: long running process/transaction. With it you can avoid most of the painfull parts (writing custom activities, etc). When most of the logic is outside of the WF (in "agents"), you won't need to refresh the WF too often, it's only the backbone of the long running process. The week part is the scalability and storage: I've created a github project to port WF to Orleans, where Orleans provides storage, scheduler and gives scalability and portability. https://github.com/OrleansContrib/Orleans.Activities

Comment: I agree, having the orchestration part separated from agent part is right. The next question that arises for me is what would you use to implement the agent part, Orleans?. Because, as I understand, an agent will be fired at each node of the workflow, but those agents will also need to handle state persistance and resources to execute their work. For example, an agent could be a computation that needs to be executed over a specific cluster that contains the correct dlls and packages to do the work.

Comment: I don't know much about using Orleans (yet) so can't comment about it. Looks like you want to have a "persistent agent" of sorts? The simplest approach is to store any state-full data in a database, and when launching an agent, have the agent read the state from the database before performing the specified task. The orchestration process would feed a "work context ID" (such as the workflow instance GUID, for example) that the agent can use for keeping track of what its working on. Bottom line is to have the persistence data in a database somewhere.